# What is the best way to go about this

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

so, a little backstory. I have been working on a cel shaded 3d rpg for a while now. it' s going to have the options to switch between action based and turn based. that's for a later time though.

the question I have is I want to add a way to damage the enemy when the sword collides with it. I know onCollisionEnter is a way to do it, I also know raycasts are a different but more complicated way to do it.
I want for each sword swing to damage the enemy (Slimes for now, more enemies later.) incremently instead of an instant death. I have tried onCollisionEnter before, but couldn't get it to decrease in increments.
just, well... an instant **death**

the onCollisionEnter I have used is with the comparetag<> function.

it might also be important to know that I am on unity 2019.4.X

I have tried to use unity 2020.x but it was too taxing on my PC, as every time I would do something an application load thing would appear and it would be annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raycasts is not suitable for you if you are not throwing swords. You are using the correct way (collision), but you are missing a point:

- This does not happen once when there is a collision. Lots of collisions happen consecutively.

To avoid this, you can close one of the colliders for a short time when there is a collision. (this means that: If the enemy has 100 health and we are decreasing 20 health with each hit, more than 5 collisions occur consecutively. Therefore, we are killing the enemy in one fell swoop.)

Or you can use a bool value (for example `swordSwingCollisionActive`). If the collision occurs after the sword is swung, you set this bool value to `true`. When the sword swing is over, you go `false` again. Just write `if (swordSwingCollisionActive) return;` at the beginning of `OnCollisionEnter`.

Comment: Thanks, man!  I'll try it and get back to you if something goes wrong.

would Raycasts be good for when the slime sees the player it enters battle mode?

I have 2 separate level UI. one for normal mode, when you are just exploring and one for battle mode with an action menu.

Comment: If you want to detect the enemy by distance, you can use `Physics.OverlapSphere`. And you can use raycasts to find out if a target is in a direction or not. You can think of Raycast as a wispy beam.